Classifying spaces of spheres
I am currently reading Topology of fibre bundles by Steenrod in an effort to understand Milnor's exotic sphere paper. In section 19 we are given the classifying theorem for universal bundles that states the following:
Let $K$ be a $CW$- complex, $\mathscr{B}$ the universal bundle for a group $G$. Let $X$ be its base space. Then there is a bijection between the homotopy classes of maps of $K$ into $X$ and principal bundles with group $G$ over $K$.
Then, it is shown that there always exist a universal bundle for any compact Lie group. In particular, it exists a universal fibre bundle over a space $BO(n)$ for the group $O_n$.Thus, I deduce that since $S^n$ is a $CW$-complex, the classifying theorem gives us the following:
$\pi_n(BO(n+1)) \text{ is in 1-1 correspondence with } Prin_{O(n+1)}(S^n)$.
Lastly it is shown that if $\mathscr{B}$ is a universal bundle for $G$ and $X$ is its base space, then $\pi_n(X) \approx \pi_{n-1}(G)$. This leads then to the following: $k$-sphere bundles are classified by $\pi_{n-1}(SO(k+1))$.
Note: in the latter statement I am using three facts:the classifying theorem, the fact that classifying principal bundles over $X$ with group $G$ is the same as classifying fibre bundles with group $G$ over $X$, and that $\pi_nO(k)= \pi_n(SO(k))$ for $n \geq 1$.
Are my deductions right?

The classifying theorem states that $[S^n, BO(n + 1)] \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Prin}_{O(n + 1)}(S^n)$. Note that the set at the left is the set of free homotopy classes, not pointed ones, and can be identified with $\pi_n(BO(n + 1))$ iff $BO(n + 1)$ is ($n$-)simple, which in general it isn't. Otherwise you obtain that $[S^n, BO(n + 1)] \cong \pi_n(BO(n + 1), x_0) / \pi_1(BO(n + 1), x_0)$ for a suitable $x_0$.

I might have gotten slightly confused there: I'm actually not sure whether all the $BO(n)$ are simple (I believe somebody asked this a while ago but didn't get answer, but I can't find the question right now). In any case, you would need to argue this for that bijection to hold.

Thanks, that's what I was missing. I think they are not n- simple, at least for all $n$. Applying the long exact sequence will probably prove fruitful.

Okay so I think, I've got it. The identification that can be made is this one: the principal bundles over $S^n$ with group $O(n+1)$ are in a 1-1 correspondence with the factor group $\pi_{n-1}(O(n))/\pi_0(O(n))$. This correspondence is given by the classifying bundle + the identification $\pi_{n-1}(G) \approx \pi_n(X)$ for universal bundles.
